# How to display the message coming from the API(i.e the custom message sent by the BE from the component) other than message interceptor error 404

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to handle global error, where i am making use of an HttpErrorInterceptor

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {retry, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@Injectable()
// eslint-disable-next-line require-jsdoc
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  // eslint-disable-next-line require-jsdoc
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            retry(1),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              let errorMessage = '';
              if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                // client-side error
                errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
              } else {
                // server-side error
                if (error.status == 404) {
                  errorMessage = 'Resource not found.';
                } else {
                  errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
                }
              }
              return throwError(() => errorMessage);
            }),
        );
  }
}
export const ErrorInterceptorProvider = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
  multi: true,
};
```

but i want to display the custom error message coming from the Back end when the error status is other than 404.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  loading: boolean;
  error: string;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  getUsers() {
    this.loading = true;

    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      users => {
        console.log(users);
        this.loading = false;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        if (err.error && err.error.customErrorMessage) {
        this.error = error;
        this.customErrorMessage = err;
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

How should I other than the 404 error redirect the errormessage in the interceptor to display the customErrorMessage from the component.

Comment: So you have to problem with displaying the error message or BE error message is not coming to the component?

Comment: @GouthamHarshith,  i am able to display the error messages, but instead of displaying the generic error message that i am getting from Interceptor, i want to display the message that the BE is sending via API
Repsonse: {
    "errorCode": "404",
    "customErrorMessage": "Resourse Not Found"
}
That is i want the customErrorMessage variable coming from the response to be mapped in the interceptor. 
How to do so? is there any way?